# Set style to html tags by conditions with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is html like below,

```
<em>+5.0</em>
<em>+3.2</em>
<em>-2.4</em>
<em>-4.6</em>
```

I want to set colors each numbers following conditions. 
If the number greater than 0, the color will be red. 
and others would be blue. the output would be

```
+5.0 (red color)
+3.2 (red color)
-2.4 (blue color)
-4.6 (blue color)
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

**what I tried**

```
if ($('em').text() > 0){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
}
```

But `$('em').text()` is not one element, I could't apply style properly. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), to maintain the `this` context

```
$('em').each(function(){
    if (+$(this).text() > 0){
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
})
```

OR, [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) can be used.

```
$('em').filter(function(){
    return +$(this).text() > 0;
}).css('color', 'red')
```

Note: I have use `+` to convert the text to number.

Answer (score 0):

loop through all em with $.each, and use parseFloat() .Try this:

```
$('em').each(function(){
  if (parseFloat($(this).text()) > 0){
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over each `em` element, check the contents and apply the style in turn:

```
$("em").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() > 0) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');  
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67LvLxth/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert the text to integer & then compare with 0

```
$('em').each(function(){
var _getText = parseInt($(this).text())
if(_getText >0){
$(this).css('color','blue');
}
else{
$(this).css('color','red');
}

})
```

Check [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/s98upcty/) for working jsfiddle